# Shell Scripting - Must not generate extra messages and its not but says I am

Tags: shell, unix

There is a similar question about this issue. But not the same solution.

I am to create a shell script that takes two parameters:
1.the desired file extension
2.the name of a single file to be renamed with that extension

The script should rename the file with the desired file extension. If the file does not exist, it should print out "fileName: No such file". It is producing this message but the professor's tests says it is producing unexpected messages(extra messages) but it is not. My shell script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
fileExtension="$1"
shift
oldName="${@}"
extension=${oldName##*.}
if test -r "$oldName"
then
   if "$fileExtension" == $oldName.*
   then
      echo "$oldName"
   else
      newName="${oldName%.*}.$fileExtension"
      mv "$oldName" "$newName"
   fi
else 
   echo "$oldName": No such file
fi
```

Everytime I test it, it produces "fileName: no such file" and nothing else.

The test is executed by

```
./chExt2.sh cpp aardvark.CPP
```

where aardvark.CPP is not on the directory.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Ask your professor to fix the test to *display* what "extra messages" the code produces. It's 2013 and error messages should be more useful than `"Error"`

Comment: Your line `echo "$oldName"` probably produces an "extra message". Chances are he's throwing a number of test cases at it, including one you missed testing somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Your shebang is telling your shell to use `/bin/sh` to run the script.  `/bin/sh` is typically a symlink to the real/default shell on the host.  For example, mine's bash:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 27  2009 /bin/sh -> bash
```

It sounds like your professor's computer's `/bin/sh` is using a different shell than you are [expecting].  This script runs fine in `ksh` or `bash`, for example, but produces "extra output" if `/bin/sh` is `tcsh`:

```
fileExtension=cpp: Command not found.
Illegal variable name.
```

Comment: I am only allowed to use /bin/sh or /bin/csh. When running the test it says it is looking for a .sh file, can I use /bin/csh in a .sh file? And could that solve the issue?

Comment: file extensions don't matter in unix.  you could name your script "awesome.bananas" and it would run the same way.  your shell is going to look at the #! line for what to use to run your script.  so you can set this to `#! /bin/csh` if that's what shell you want running your script.

Comment: I really didn't want to use csh, but I guess I don't have a choice. Here is the file switched to csh. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Now it keeps saying illegal variable name.

    #!/bin/csh
    set ext="$1"
    shift
    set oldName="${@}"
    set nonext=${oldName##*.}
    if ( -r "$oldName" ) then
       if { "$ext" == "$oldName.*" ) then
          echo "$oldName"
       else
          set newName=`${oldName%.*}.$ext`
          mv "$oldName" "$newName"
       endif
    else
       echo "$oldName": No such file
    endif

Comment: well before you try learning csh, you should really verify what's happening with your professor.  i find it *very* unlikely that his `/bin/sh` points to `csh` (this would break alot of things because they two shells have very different core syntax).  do what Aaron Digulla suggests and find out what the error/"extra messages" are and what's actually different about your professor's test environment.

Comment: I asked my professor & he said try it where the file does exist & I get errors. Here is an edited version.

    #!/bin/sh
    fileExtension="$1"
    shift
    oldName="${@}"
    extension=${oldName##*.}
    if [ -f "$oldName" ]
    then
       if $fileExtension -ne ${oldName#*.}
       then
          newName="${oldName%.*}.$fileExtension"
          mv "$oldName" "$newName"
       else
          echo $oldName
       fi
    else
       echo $oldName: No such file
    fi
The error I get is:
./chExt2.sh: 8: ./chExt.sh: CPP: not found
aardvark.cpp (<--The original name of the file)

Comment: I edited again and this time, it changes the extension but I still get errors.

    #!/bin/sh
    fileExtension="$1"
    shift
    oldName="${@}"
    extension=${oldName##*.}
    if test -f "$oldName"
    then
       if $fileExtension -eq ${oldName#*.}
       then
          echo "$oldName"
       else
          newName="${oldName%.*}.$fileExtension"
          mv "$oldName" "$newName"
       fi
    else
       echo $oldName: No such file
    fi

errors: ./chExt2.sh: 8: ./chExt2.sh CPP: not found